# React Native createBottomTabNavigator Add customized color from constants

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-stylesheet

I am working on the implementation of a [createBottomTabNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html). I added a *tabBarIcon* and I would like to use a global color that I have defined in a *const* in a global styles file as shown below:

**global.style.js**

```
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";

export const Colors = {
 ...
  orange: "#F59200",
 ...
};
```

**Router.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
...

import { StackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import { createBottomTabNavigator, BottomTabBar } from "react-navigation-tabs";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome";
import Colors from "MyApp/app/config/global.style";
...
import HomeScreen from "../screens/HomeScreen";
...

export const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
  HomeScreen: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: () => ({
      tabBarLabel: "My Home Screen",
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        // color={Colors.orange} does not work here 
        <Icon name="rocket" color={Colors.orange} size={24} />
      )
    })
  },
...
```

I found a bunch of examples that show how to add the color directly, which works:

```
HomeScreen: {
        screen: HomeScreen,
        navigationOptions: () => ({
          tabBarLabel: "My Home Screen",
          tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
            <Icon name="rocket" color="#F59200" size={24} />
          )
        })
      }
```

But I would like to know if there is a way to pass the *const Colors*  value instead.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I can't pass a const or a global value to tabBarOptions, only hard code it with a number

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to to the navigation or follow through [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html#bottomtabnavigatorconfig)

```
tabBarOptions: {
  activeTintColor: 'green',
  inactiveTintColor: 'white',
  inactiveBackgroundColor:'green'
},
```